# What does the Active image on my flag indicate?

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

What does this [image] image mean?

I see this image on posts that I've flagged.

[image]

And what about this flagged post? It's marked as helpful but not marked as duplicate.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It means your flag has not yet been processed. It is active until it is either marked helpful, disputed or declined.

When you flag a post as a duplicate, it is added to the *Close Review queue* and awaits review by people with enough reputation to help review posts. If enough people agree the post is closed and your flag will be marked as *helpful*. If people disagree and the post is removed from the queue again, then the flag will be marked as *declined*.

Comment: Is that different between I commented this duplicate and mark it as duplicated with flag option?

Comment: I have updated my question.